# Container View or UIViewController for tableView with SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in `storyboard` that will be a sliding up menu. I want to place it in a `UITableView`. If I place it as subview of `UITableView` and prevent it from scrolling, it gets the look I want, with one problem, the section headers of tableview scroll above subview.

Now, in order to prevent this behavior, I could reduce tableview frame, but it doesn't work because my subview is inside that same frame, right?

So , if that is true, what is the best way to achieve this? Place both screens inside a third `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to put other views inside a table view. Bad news.

If your table view is managed by a UITableViewController then that's really all you can have in the table view (unless your views are inside cells, or in headers or footers.)

If you ARE using table view controllers to manage your table view(s), I suggest you create a container view on the view controller that needs to contain the table view, then control-drag an embed segue to the table view controller. That way the table view controller becomes a child view controller of the main VC, and you can put other view elements on the screen to your heart's content.